# How to update value in JSON field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am making an API with Django Rest Framework and I have a problem. When I try to change the value of JSONfield from False to True (or vice versa) it doesn't change the value of specific key, but it changes the whole JSONfield to True(or False). How do I change the value of just a key?

My models.py:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", unique=True, max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fruit = models.JSONField(default={"Apple":False, "Pear": True, "Orange":False}) #This is that field

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

My serializers.py:

```
class FruitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ["fruit"]

        def update(self, instance, validated_data): 
            instance.fruit = validated_data.get('fruit', instance.fruit)
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

My views.py:

```
class UpdateFruitView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FruitSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        fruit = request.data.get("fruit")
        select_fruit = request.user.fruit[fruit]
        if select_fruit == False:
            select_fruit = True
            data_to_change = {'fruit': select_fruit}
            serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user, data=data_to_change, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                self.perform_update(serializer)

            return Response(serializer.data)

        if select_fruit == True:
            select_fruit = False
            data_to_change = {'fruit': select_fruit}
            serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user, data=data_to_change, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                self.perform_update(serializer)

            return Response(serializer.data)
```

How I want the JSON field to look like:

- before: `{"Apple":False, "Pear": True, "Orange":False}`
- after I send request for Apple to change : `{"Apple":True, "Pear": True, "Orange":False}`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rethink your db structure but there is solution for your problem:

Depending on what you sent in order to update `fruit` field:

This is probably what you are doing now.

If this is the payload:
`{"Apple": True}`
Then when you set instance.fruit to validated_data["fruit"] your JSONField has replaced value instead of updated.
To update do this in serializers.py.
`instance.fruit = {**instance.fruit, **validated_data.get('fruit', instance.fruit)}`
Here is a bit more about `**` operator https://geekflare.com/python-unpacking-operators/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I do the changes I still get the same result as before